# same program same compiler but I got different output in c

Tags: c

```
\\First program
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int array[30],n,c,d,position,swap;
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter the legth of array\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("Enter element in array\n");
 for(c=0;c<n;c++)
 { scanf("%d",&array[c]); }
 for(c=0;c<(n-1);c++)
 {
  position = c;
  for(d=c+1;d<n;d++)
  {
  if(array[position] > array[d])
  position = d;
  }
 if(position != c)
  { swap = array[c];
   array[c]= array[position];
   array[position] = swap;
  }
 }
printf("Sorted list\n");
for(c=0;c<n;c++);
{printf("%d\n",array[c]);}
getch();
}


\\Second program
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
 int array[30],n,c,d,position,swap;
 clrscr();
 printf("Enter the legth of array\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 printf("Enter element in array\n");
 for(c=0;c<n;c++)
 { scanf("%d",&array[c]); }
 for(c=0;c<(n-1);c++)
 {
  position = c;
  for(d=c+1;d<n;d++)
  {
   if(array[position] > array[d])
   position = d;
  }
  if(position != c)
  { swap = array[c];
    array[c]= array[position];
    array[position] = swap;
  }
 }
 printf("Sorted list\n");
 for(c=0;c<n;c++);
 {printf("%d\n",array[c]);}
 getch();
 return 0; 
}
```

These two program is the program for selection sort. I think the first program and second program is almost the same but the output is not same. I use turbo c to run these two program

In the first program, i copy from internet and the result is true (intput is 2 1/output is 1 2). For second program, i try to do it by my own (intput is 2 1/output is 3) and the result is false.

Everyone plz help me. I got confuse. Thank you :]

Comment: "almost the same" is not the same as "the same" - find the difference between the two, and you'll probably spot the reason for the different output.

Comment: `#include<conio.h>` and `return 0;` were the only differences that I found with a tool.

Comment: Sounds like undefined behaviour. You probably have uninizialized variables and/or you access your array out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both programs are wrong and you get undefined bahaviour:

```
for(c=0;c<n;c++);  // << the ; should not be here
                   // now c contains 2
                   // and you print array[2] once
                   // and as array[2] hasn't bee initialized
                   // printf will print a more or less random value

{printf("%d\n",array[c]);}
getch();
```

Corrected (and correctly formatted) version

```
for (c = 0; c < n;c++)
{
  printf("%d\n",array[c]);}
}
getch();
```

If you had formatted your code correctly from the beginning you probably would have spotted the problem by yourself.